# Date of 7 days before today

Tags: string, matlab, date, variables, time

I give current day in a string in MATLAB. For example if today is `'20180703'`, I need 7 strings containing:

```
'20180702'
'20180701'
'20180630' 
'20180629'
'20180628'
'20180627'
'20180626'
```

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html please read the documentation and examples before asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something like:

```
lastSevenDays = arrayfun(@(offset) datestr(now-offset, 'yyyymmdd'), 1:7, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

or more matlaby:

```
datestr(now - days(1:7), 'yyyymmdd')
```

Comment: Did this change recently? I'm using 2017a and there mm is month.
According to https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html mm is month.

Comment: In 2016a, 'MM' is for month.

Comment: @Evgeny it is dependent on the function used. Older functions, like `datestr`, use `'mm'` where newer functions, like `datetime`, use `'MM'`. Please refer to the documentation before making declarations about their input formats.

Comment: @excaza, my fault. It is quite unexpected that two similar functions use different formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
t = datetime('20180703', 'InputFormat', 'yyyyMMdd')
t = t - days(1:7)
datestr(t, 'yyyymmdd')
```

**Edit.**
As **excaza** pointed out, `datetime` and `datestr` use different input format. Hence, `'MM'` in the first function, and `'mm'` in the second one.